# When I drag a UI button to prefabs it doesn't add child component

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to make a prefab of UI Button with it's text. I created a prefabs folder and when I drag my button to the project's prefabs folder, I can't see the text as shown in the tutorial I'm following. I want to change the text of every button I created that is connected to that prefab.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what tutorial you are watching but it seems to be for an older Unity Version.

I can see you are using `Unity 2019` and back in `Unity 2018.3` they added [Nested Prefabs](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2018/06/20/introducing-new-prefab-workflows/). Also see the [Prefab Manuals](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Prefabs.html).

They work a bit differently now.

You don't directly edit Prefabs anymore but rather either <kbd>double-click</kbd> it in the *ProjectView* or in the *Hierachy* click on the little arrow <kbd>></kbd> next to it in order to enter the [*Prefab Mode*](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/EditingInPrefabMode.html) or since you already selected it in the ProjectView simply hit <kbd>Open Prefab</kbd> in the *Inspector*

[image]

This opens your prefab as if it would be a Scene in the hierachy and now you can edit everything in it.

---

Alternatively simply make your changes in one of the instances in the Hierachy (current Scene) and then apply them back to the prefab as explained in [Editing a Prefab via its instances](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/EditingPrefabViaInstance.html)

either for each changed property via <kbd>right-click</kbd>

[image]

or for all proerties of the entire component via the <kbd>Override</kbd> dropdown ont he top-right

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is as its intended to work, in order to see insides of a prefab either open it in the editor or place on scene